# peewee.OperationalError: table gist has no column named name

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, peewee

I keep getting this error in my code when it seems that there is no problem with it. I am using Peewee and SQLite with Flask.

Here is my code.

```
from peewee import *

import datetime

DB = SqliteDatabase("gist.db")

class Gist(Model):
    name = CharField()
    content = TextField()
    description = TextField()
    join_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
       database = DB

def initialize():
    DB.connect()
    DB.create_tables([Gist], safe=True)
    DB.close()
```

Here is the code that creates the instance:

```
@app.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def index():
    form = forms.GistForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        models.Gist.create(name=form.name.data,
                           content=form.content.data,
                           description=form.description.data)
        flash("Message posted! Thanks!", "success")
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)
```

Thanks for any help that you can give!

EDIT: Stacktrace for those interested

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exc
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispa
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_use
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispa
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_r
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "B:\Sites\GistClone\app.py", line 21, in index
    description=form.description.data)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 4494, in create
    inst.save(force_insert=True)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 4680, in save
    pk_from_cursor = self.insert(**field_dict).execute()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3213, in execute
    cursor = self._execute()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2628, in _execute
    return self.database.execute_sql(sql, params, self.require_commit)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3461, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3285, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_args), traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 127, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 3454, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.OperationalError: table gist has no column named name
```

Comment: please also post stacktrace.

Comment: Done. @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error and fixed it by deleting the database .db file (in your case "gist.db").

If after the database file was created, you modified or added any model fields, then peewee doesn't recognize the modified and/or new fields in the original database and throws this error. After deleting the old .db file, a new one with the most recent fields will be recreated upon start-up and that resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

As @davejlin wrote, if you delete the db file and recreate it, the problem will be solved.
Alternatively, if you have important data in the database, you can use [Schema Migrations](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#migrate).

From [peewee docs](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#creating-model-tables):

> After you have created your tables, if you choose to modify your database schema (by adding, removing or otherwise changing the columns) you will need to either:
>
> - Drop the table and re-create it.
> - Run one or more ALTER TABLE queries. Peewee comes with a schema migration tool which can greatly simplify this. Check the [schema migrations](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#migrate) docs for details.